# How Can i Read only one record from mdr.Read() command in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

x is string array and from a table in the database i want to read a particular row for example: i want to read only 2nd row.

```
while (mdr.Read())
{
    x = mdr[1].ToString().Split(' ');
    y = 0;
    while (y < x.Length)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x[y]);
        y++;
    }                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a counter which is incremented at every iteration and your code is executed only once that counter reaches the number you want.
I.E.:

```
int i = 0;    
while (mdr.Read())
    {
      if(i == 1) //i is 1 when it's the second row
      {
          x = mdr[1].ToString().Split(' ');
          y = 0;
          while (y < x.Length)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(x[y]);
              y++;
          } 
      }
      i++;                       
    }
```

Also remember to sort your data in the query, as databases don't always return data in the same order if not specified to do so!